# Include images in Sharepoint RSS Feed

Tags: image, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, rss

I am using an RSS feed in SharePoint 2010 to display a news feed.  The news feed includes images and I would like these to be visible in my RSS on the Sharepoint Site.  What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example I found: http://zioed.wordpress.com/2012/02/24/customizing-the-sharepoint-2010-rss-viewer-web-part-part-1-of-a-two-part-post-2/